# Travelling to the UK during Coronavirus; where can I find who is exempt from the 14-day quarantine?

Tags: uk, covid-19

When traveling to the UK during the current Coronavirus pandemic, I read [there was a compulsory 14-day quarantine](https://www.itv.com/news/2020-05-09/mandatory-quarantine-for-uk-arrivals-would-be-devastating-trade-body-warns/).

- Where can I find who is exempt from this quarantine?

<sub>Info as of 20/06/20</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by @Daniil, you can find the full list [here.](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules)

I have gone through the list, wondering if I did fit one of the exemptions. I do not.

In short, you can enter without quarantine or self isolation if you come to the UK to work in a restricted number of jobs or when you transport needed supplies or people who are going to work in essential jobs.
The list is very precise and detailed, including, among others, the drivers and staff of the Channel tunnel trains, people arriving to work for growers of food plants (but not other plants,) and people who repair BBC broadcasting facilities.

Tourists, relatives of residents and girlfriends of citizens are not included.

Answer (score 3):

> - **Who is exempt from this quarantine?**

The [UK Goverment](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/travel-advice-novel-coronavirus#if-youre-travelling-abroad) posted a section about this:

> ## Re-entering the UK
>
> When you return, you must follow the [rules for entering the UK](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control). You must:
>
> - [provide your journey and contact details](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk) up to 48 hours before you’re due to arrive in the UK
> - not leave the place you’re staying for the first 14 days you’re in the UK except in very limited situations (known as ‘self-isolating’). See the guidance for [England](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk), [Scotland](https://www.gov.scot/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-public-health-checks-at-borders/pages/overview/), [Wales](https://gov.wales/how-self-isolate-when-you-travel-wales-coronavirus-covid-19) and [Northern Ireland](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-advice)

The list of people exempt from this quarantine is published [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules).

<sub>Info as of 20/06/20</sub>